# Sort by code column multiple data.tables in R into same number of data.tables without binding the data.tables (due to memory limits)

Tags: r, performance, sorting, data.table

I have many CSV's containing a huge amount of data that is unsorted by code across all CSV's in the set. I'd like to sort the codes across the whole set saving groups of codes to CSV's together, keeping the same number of CSV's as before when they were unsorted.  **I can't bind them together, sort, and split (as I usually would) because I have to keep the CSV's separated due to memory limits.** My real dataset is billions of lines split across hundreds of CSV's like this.

For example, if after fread each of the data table examples below:

Reproducible data:

```
###Really I would fread() each of these, but reproducible here
data1 <- data.table(code=rep(c(1:2000),times=500),
                   data1=rep(c(10001:12000),times=500), 
                   data2=rep(c(20001:22000),times=500))
data2 <- data.table(code=rep(c(1:2000),times=500),
                    data1=rep(c(10001:12000),times=500), 
                    data2=rep(c(20001:22000),times=500))
data3 <- data.table(code=rep(c(1:2000),times=500),
                    data1=rep(c(10001:12000),times=500), 
                    data2=rep(c(20001:22000),times=500))
data4 <- data.table(code=rep(c(1:2000),times=500),
                    data1=rep(c(10001:12000),times=500), 
                    data2=rep(c(20001:22000),times=500))
```

I'd like to sort by the code for each of data (there is a variable number in reality) and save as the same number of csv's

The below is an example of the above data in the format I'd like. So there are codes 1-2000 on the original data.tables, here the codes are split so codes 1:500 is on desired1, codes 501:1000 are on desired2, codes 1001:1500 are on desired3, and codes 1501:2000 are on desired4.

Reproducible desired data:

```
###I'd use fwrite to save each one of these as a csv to file

desired1 <- data.table(code=rep(c(1:500),times=2000),
                                data1=rep(c(10001:10500),times=2000), 
                                data2=rep(c(20001:20500),times=2000))
desired2 <- data.table(code=rep(c(501:1000),times=2000),
                                data1=rep(c(10501:11000),times=2000), 
                                data2=rep(c(20501:21000),times=2000))
desired3 <- data.table(code=rep(c(1001:1500),times=2000),
                                data1=rep(c(11001:11500),times=2000), 
                                data2=rep(c(21001:21500),times=2000))
desired4 <- data.table(code=rep(c(1501:2000),times=2000),
                                data1=rep(c(11501:12000),times=2000), 
                                data2=rep(c(21501:22000),times=2000))
```

In reality I have 500 or more CSV's. What is the fastest way to sort them then save all of the same code to the same csv, while still splitting across the same number of csv's as the original unsorted files? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm ok let me double check it akrun, thanks

Comment: Based on the description, I am thinking that you want to bind all the data together (memory issue) and then do some kind of splitting?

Comment: It's a total memory issue exactly.

Comment: Binding together won't work because I can't have a data.table that big in memory. This is billions of lines if you combined the csv's

Comment: I guess this is a one-off problem? Or something you'd possibly do multiple times? AKA why is this a "speed" concern?

Comment: Then you can do a `for` loop

Comment: As a one-off problem, I'd make a first pass looping over all the data to tabulate the counts of `code` across the universe of files. This will help you plan which codes go to which files. Then maybe use `split.data.table` and `fwrite` with `append = TRUE` on a second pass over the data.

Comment: Do you care at all about `code` balancing (i.e. would you like the number of rows among output files to be similar)? And what's wrong with just putting each code into its own file (rather than tying yourself to matching #input and #output)

Comment: @MichaelChirico When I do analysis on the csv's I find having less fread()'s and and grouping compiled files by code is much faster than loading a csv of each code's rows

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is your data containing only numerics? Does the column you want to sort fit in memory?

Comment: Is R really the right tool for this ? With command line you could try to bind everything together (it's very fast), then sort (I have no idea how it deals with memory, but hopefully it's smart), then split into the same amount of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop that sequentially `rbind` would be memory efficient

```
out <- data1[code %in% 1:500]
for(i in 2:4) out <- rbind(out, get(paste0('data', i))[code %in% 1:500])
identical(out, desired1) 
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This works well, but since it iterates in a loop is fairly slow. Since it binds and I don't want to hold anything in memory since these data are huge, I assume we couldn't parallelize this with doFuture or mclapply across the i because to not use memory it has to iterate one by one?

Comment: @NealBarsch  Or another option if you are not doing anything with the full dataset would be to have write.csv within the loop and use `append = TRUE` so that you don't need to create the big 'out'

Comment: Ahh good idea, using fwrite() from data.table on these is better than write.csv, fwrite also has the append. If I do it that way I might be able to make it parallel since it's just appending, you agree?

Comment: @NealBarsch  Yes, that will be good idea and by reading the comments, MichaelChirico commented among those lines

Answer (score 0):

```
mm = function(x){
  a = table(x)
  rep(1:unique(a),length(a))
}

Map(function(x,y)set(x,j="code",value=mm(x[,code])+y),mget(ls(pattern = "data")),c(0,500,1000,1500))

$data4
         code data1 data2
      1: 1501 10001 20001
      2: 1502 10002 20002
      3: 1503 10003 20003
      4: 1504 10004 20004
      5: 1505 10005 20005
     ---                 
 999996: 1996 11996 21996
 999997: 1997 11997 21997
 999998: 1998 11998 21998
 999999: 1999 11999 21999
1000000: 2000 12000 22000
```

This changes the original data as it calls by reference. ie try calling `data2` you will see that it has changed. If you do not want this behavior, you might consider using the function `copy` ie `set(copy(x),....`